# Converting XML to special "plain text" format?

Tags: xml, dokuwiki

I have some very long XML files. How to convert them to "Dokuwiki table"?

The XML document is like:

```
<xml row>
<name>...</name>
<type>...</type>
.
.
.
</xml row>
<xml row>
.
.
.
```

The dokuwiki table like:

```
^ I'm a table header ^ Me too ^
| I'm a table content | Me too |
```

Comment: Try the following approach, open xml in Excel to convert xml to table first. Then use CONCATENATE with | to convert the table to wiki markup.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of tasks the traditional unix toolkit is your best friend. Here `sed` or `awk` can solve it very well. But if you are not used to these tools, then you can even use any texteditor's replace function, in this easy case at least, it can solve the problem here as I see. Just replace `<name>`, `</name>\n<type>` and `</type>` with `|`, then cut the garbage at beginning/end of file.
*(Did not try it now, just first guess, maybe you will have to deal more with `\n`? and the `<xml row>` needs to replaced with empty string also, and if there are more tags the same applies. Just try it and you will see! You can solve it I'm sure!)*